# Apache ServiceMix! 5.0.0 : Apache Karaf 2.3.4 : "camel:route-list" command issue

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

---

### I have the following scenario:

I've migrated a few days ago from Apache ServiceMix! 4.5.3 to version 5.0.0 and I have encoutered a small issue, at least I think.

My main Spring configuration file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
  xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
  ">

  <!-- Import the First CamelContext -->
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/camel-context/first-context.xml" />

  <!-- Import the Second CamelContext -->
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/camel-context/second-context.xml" />

  <!-- Import the Third CamelContext -->
  <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/camel-context/third-context.xml" />

</beans>
```

When using the older version of ServiceMix! (4.5.3), I was typing `camel:route-list` and `camel:context-list` in the Karaf console, I was seeing all 3 contexts (First, Seconds, Third CamelContext) with their own routes. It was ok.

After migrating to ServiceMix! 5.0.0 (using the exact code), when I issue those commands, I only see the last context `Third CamelContext`. It's not ok. Although the bundle runs ok, the routes are there, functioning ok. I can see them in a web console (like hawtio).

### Question

Is there an issue with ServiceMix! 5.0.0 or I must modify my code somehow? I want to see all of my contexts/routes in the Karaf console, really helps debugging...

Comment: try to flip the order of the import to see if you see another of the Camel.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I always see only the last CamelContext in Karaf... no matter how many CamelContexts I have.

Comment: What can you see in JMX, eg if you connect to karaf using JConsole? And do your < camelContext > use any custom id attribute, to set a name for the context? And if so make sure they are unique names.

Comment: When connecting to Karaf using the console I see all the contexts/routes, it's ok. I have a custom ID attribute for each context and it's not the same. I've remove the custom ID attribute and the same thing happened... If I install the same bundle in an older version of ServiceMix! (4.5.3), Karaf behaves ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug in Apache Camel 2.12.3 [1] and it was fixed from Apache Camel 2.12.4 on. Thanks for sharing that, Ibsen!

[1] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7545